# Is this type of clash common? cream / compiz, or is it a bug?

Tags: compiz, cream

I've got an odd situation happening with a "cream" dialog...

Can anyone else duplicate this behaviour, or is it just my system?
... or is it a bug?

**My settings**
`Lucid 10.04`
`Compiz` filter: "Scale" -- "Initiate Window Picker" 
.                 Binding: **initiate_edge** = **Top Left**

`cream`: Run it **maximized**, or at least with its top edge touching the lower edge of the panel..
... In a scrap file, type "yyuryyubicuryy4me."
... Exit  `cream` (Alt+F4, mouse, menu, it doesn't matter which)
... In the Yes/No/Cancel dialog, click "No" (or **any** button)

**The problem:**
Any **action** on the dialog causes Compiz to display its **"Initiate Window Picker"** window!

**The problem setting(?)**
When I change the **initiate_edge** setting to **None**, the behaviour is normal.

I don't use **cream** much, but I don't remember it doing this when I first tried it a few weeks ago (but maybe it did, and I didn't pay attention to it).

Is this a cream bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried **gvim** under the same conditions.  It behaved properly.

Even if **cream** was behaving normally a month ago, it isn't now. 
... because they both use the same version of **gvim**, the issue is unique to **cream**.

Well, whatever is causing this, be it **cream** or something else, the net result is a "bug".

I'll uninstall **cream** and use **gvim**... Problem solved!